machine learning - data science - data analysis
I have a research project in the machine learning area. In this study, dataset contains more than 4000 numbers categorized in four columns. I am going to find or predict a possible relation between the third and fourth columns, considering the first and second columns. Please let me know if you have any idea and suggestions? Could you please help me what method may be useful?

You need to understand what these 'numbers' are. In data science, and all other statistical fields, domain knowledge is critical. Only when you have a practical understanding of your data can you then select the best model. Try answering some questions like:

Should these variable be related at all?
Are there any third variables that might
explain both?
Is the relationship between your variables likely to be the same across all your data?

Once you've done that, my only piece of advise it start start simple. Perhaps a OLS regression model is a good place to start.
